# fastlane sigh issue with input asking for more information

Tags: fastlane

I'm trying to use `sigh` and I am a bit confused. When I type the below line:

```
sigh username:"me@example.com" app_identifier:"com.example"
```

It logs in with my user name but then gives me the prompt:

```
[21:19:44]: Successfully logged in
[21:19:44]: Fetching profiles...
[21:19:44]: To not be asked about this value, you can specify it using 'app_identifier'
The bundle identifier of your app:
```

When I type the below line:

```
 sigh -a com.example -u me@example.com
```

I do not get the prompt. What am I doing wrong in the first one? The first one from what I understand is what I can use in the `fastlane` file for automation, which is why this is important. I read the below on this:

https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/tree/master/sigh

as well as the `sigh --help` documentation.

My lane is defined as below:

```
  desc "Get the provisioning profiles for the app"
  lane :sign do |options|
    apple_id = CredentialsManager::AppfileConfig.try_fetch_value(:apple_id)
    team_id = CredentialsManager::AppfileConfig.try_fetch_value(:team_id)
    cert(username: apple_id, team_id: team_id)
    sigh(app_identifier: options[:bundle_id], username: apple_id)
  end
```

The part where `sigh` is I get the same prompt. Is there a way to remove it?

**UPDATE**

The following works:

```
sigh --username "me@example.com" --app_identifier "com.example"
```

But I want it to work in `fastlane`. What am I doing wrong there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the reason was that I had some data in my `Appfile` that Fastlane didn't like. It didn't show proper error messaging, but I put one more variable that it didn't recognize and there for it failed.

One thing I learned about Fastlane is that it works well but sometimes errors are hard to debug. Make sure to read the documentation properly!

Answer (score 0):

```
sigh username:"me@example.com" app_identifier:"com.example"
```

That syntax is not supported, instead try the following from the command line

```
sigh --username "me@example.com" --app_identifier "com.example"
```

To do the same from your `Fastfile`

```
sigh(username: "me@example.com", app_identifier: "com.example")
```

Comment: How can I make it work in fastlane? Is that syntax also wrong?

Comment: I added a sample call from `fastlane`

Comment: As similar to what I have above or different?